# What can I use to securely bond a steel bracket to a tile floor?

Tags: doors, closet, barn

I am trying to avoid drilling into the concrete/tile floor because the four holes for the bracket I need to attach are within about 1 square inch of each other. The holes are a pivot/anchor point for a bifolding door to swing out from. I am worried they will cause the tile to crack at some point.

The barn door hardware is going to hold the weight of the bifold closet, so the weight of the door isn't necessarily going to be on this floor bracket. but it will pivot from it. The doors are around 60lbs each.

Is there some type of epoxy that will securely bond this anchor?

Comment: Can the doors be taken down/off without moving the anchor point?  If the epoxy is good, it should bond to the tile permanently.  Prep of the tile surface and the anchor is the most important for good bonding.  Edit the type of tile finish into your question.  Epoxy will give you only one chance to do it right, removing the epoxy will require heavy sanding/grinding.

Comment: yes the door just hangs from the top. The weight of it on the hardware on the wall not the bracket on the bottom

Answer (score 1):

Epoxy can bond to the floor so thoroughly that it cannot be removed without damaging the tile. Thereby negating the reason to not want to fasten with screws.

The pivot you want to mount does not carry weight, ( your information). There is only a need to keep the pivot point from moving laterally. This can be done with  either [adhesive caulk](https://www.lowes.com/pd/LOCTITE-Power-Grab-Heavy-Duty-White-Latex-Interior-Exterior-Construction-Adhesive-Actual-Net-Contents-9-fl-oz/1001059990?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-pnt-_-ggl-_-LIA_PNT_221_Glue-Adhesives-Caulk-Repair-_-1001059990-_-local-_-0-_-0&gclid=Cj0KCQjwx5qoBhDyARIsAPbMagC7pmVrDvoaxaeOYujx3dQeDzfwNXZNczrDvMrQ2G-ik3yr5hKFKJkaAv5YEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) or  [double sided heavy mounting tape](https://www.target.com/p/3m-extremely-strong-mounting-tape-1-34-x60-34/-/A-14413487?ref=tgt_adv_xsp&AFID=google&fndsrc=tmnv&DFA=71700000112013092&CPNG=PLA_DVM%2Ba064R000011ewqQQAQ-3M_GoogleSearch_Stationary_BTS_2023-976656&adgroup=PLA_3M&LID=700000001393753pgs&network=g&device=c&location=9052080&gclid=Cj0KCQjwx5qoBhDyARIsAPbMagDK1r0vO1XytB-SLMAomVwE3NcbebV1Wii_ITrrDcTBQ2hZHPKO9VMaAssHEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds).  Both can be removed if needed without damaging the tile.

Comment: The conditions that OP stated seems to be self-contradictory. If the pivots hold no weight, and something like caulk or tape would work, then the load would be so low that there's no good reason for the tile to crack. Is OP worry about the cracking or about restoring the tile to its original look?

Comment: the weight of the door is going to be hanging from the barn door hardware . They glide with wheels on the barn door railing. But in order for them to bi-fold it needs an anchor on the bottom. Specs say about 1/2 " clearance. In this 1/2" will sit a brass bushing inside the door aas well as the hardware peg that is supposed to be anchored to the floor.

Though the anchored hardware isnt going to bear the actual weight of the door. The peg and the door will pivot from this point.

Comment: So double side tape or caulk isnt going to cut it because they flex too much. I need a rigid peg thats secure.

Comment: @diy1361,  The double sided tape I included a link to is often used to hold body parts on automobiles.  However you believe it will not hold a post onto a floor.  Well then good luck.

Comment: yes but body parts are rarely exposed to pivoting forces. such as a family regularly opening the doors to do laundry/ Im not saying it wont hold to the floor but i want it to not "flex" on the floor.

Comment: you obviously know nothing about either product if you assume there would be "flex".